# SharePoint Keys

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, licensing, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I would like to purchase keys for SharePoint 2013 on-premise, windows server 2012, and SQL server 2012.

But I can't find any hint over the internet on how to do it.

Any assistance on the same will be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Microsoft's partner directory https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/solution-providers/home and search for **licensing**